# array of strings inside string in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, string, double-quotes

I need to give array of strings inside string.

my array will be `["2", "3"]`

```
i += "{\"name\":\"" + args.Name + "\",\"values\":[\"" + value + "\"]
```

**What I need:**

```
"{"name":"category1",,"values":["1"]},{"name":"category2","values":["2","1"]
```

**Actual output:**

```
"{"name":"category1",,"values":["1"]},{"name":"category2","values":["2,1"]
```

The double quotes of values removing and make it as string array. How to achieve this?

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 2):

Try to split your `value` by `,`.

```
i += "{\"name\":\"" + args.Name + "\",\"values\":[\"" + value.split(',') + "\"]
// ----------------------------------------------------------^^^^^^^^^^^-------
```

Comment: I am getting "value.split is not a function"

Comment: my value will be like ["1"] / ["2", "3"]/ ["2", "3", "4"] and so on

Comment: if you get `value.split is not a function`, this means that your `value` is not a type of string. What is it actually?

Answer (score 0):

try `join()` function of jQuery

```js
var value = ["2","3"];

var output = "{\"name\":\"Test\",\"values\":[\"" + value.join('","')+ "\"]";

console.log(output);
```